# адаптация акустической модели в cmu sphinx

Tags: распознавание-речи

Передо мной стоит задача - адаптировать русскую акустическую модель. Выполнял все как показано в документации но на этапе **Accumulating observation counts**  при запуске следующего скита,

```
./bw \
-hmmdir model \
-moddeffn model/mdef.txt 
-ts2cbfn .ptm. \
-feat 1s_c_d_dd \
-svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
-cmn current \
-agc none \
-dictfn zero_ru.dic \
-ctlfn lesniki.fields \
-lsnfn lesniki.transcription\
-accumdir .
```

возникает ошибка

```
INFO: s3mixw_Io.c(117): Read model/mixture_weights [4159x1x63 array]
FATAL: "mod_In.c", line 358: Number of feature streams in 
mixture_weights file 1 differs from the configured value 3, check the 
command line options
```

Ссылки на туториал и гит :
[Adapting the default acoustic model](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt)
[адаптируемая акустическая модель](https://github.com/3lolo/acoustic_model-.git)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060606/number-of-feature-streams-in-mixture-weights-file-differs-from-the-configured-va

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Nikolay Shmyrev! Отработало нормально:

```
bw \
 -hmmdir ru \
 -moddeffn ru/mdef \
 -ts2cbfn .cont. \
 -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
 -lda ru/feature_transform \
 -cmn current \
 -agc none \
 -dictfn ru/ru.dic \
 -ctlfn test.fileids \
 -lsnfn test.transcription \
 -accumdir .
```